# Assign values in Pandas series based on condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a dataframe `df` like

```
A B
1 2
3 4
```

I then want to create 2 new series

```
t = pd.Series()
r = pd.Series()
```

I was able to assign values to `t` using the condition `cond` as below

```
t = "1+" + df.A.astype(str) + '+' + df.B.astype(str)
cond = df['A']<df['B']
team[cond] = "1+" + df.loc[cond,'B'].astype(str) + '+' + df.loc[cond,'A'].astype(str)
```

But I'm having problems with `r`. I just want `r` to contain values of 2 when `con` is satisfied and 1 otherwise

If I just try

```
r = 1
r[cond] = 2
```

Then I get `TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment`

I figure I could just run a for loop through `df` and check the cases in `cond` through each row of `df`, but I was wondering if Pandas offers a more efficient way instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will laugh at how easy this is:

```
r = cond + 1
```

The reason is that `cond` is a boolean (True and False) which evaluate to 1 and 0. If you add one to it, it coerces the boolean to an int, which will mean True maps to 2 and False maps to one.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 3, 4], 
                   'B': [2, 4, 3]})

cond = df['A'] < df['B']

>>> cond + 1
0    2
1    2
2    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

When you assign 1 to r as in

```
r = 1
```

r now references the integer 1.  So when you call r[cond] you're treating an integer like a series.

You want to first create a series of ones for r the size of cond. Something like

```
r = pd.Series(np.ones(cond.shape))
```

Comment: if I try `r = pd.Series(np.ones(df.shape))`, I get `Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional
`

Comment: I think I got to work by using `len(df.index)` instead of `shape`. However, `r[cond] = 2` is not working. Why is that?

Comment: Can you try it as `r = np.ones(cond.shape)` instead of `pd.Series(np.ones(df.shape))`?

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame([{'A':1,'B':2},{'A':3,'B':4}]); cond = df['A']<df['B']; r = pd.Series(np.ones(cond.shape)); r[cond]=2;` works for me

Comment: if I try `r = np.ones(cond.shape)`, it seems to work. However `r[cond] = 2` still doesn't work: `pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series key provided
`

Comment: Arg, I misunderstood your question.  @Alexander definitely has it right.